# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code on a real device

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode12

Can anyone help here pleaaase,

I m building an app i didn t programm myself with Flutter.

It was working, we even made a test version on real devices.

Now I want to make it work locally on my pc, and then deploy it on the app store. I had problems with the podfiles because the version of Flutter had evolved since (that app was tested 6 months ago).

Now it's causing me these errors, I don't know if I should touch something in the code yet or just update some others files..., if someone has already had to do this kind of case

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

rm -f ios/Podfile ios/Podfile.lock pubspec.lock && rm -rf ios/Runner.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/ &&  flutter clean && flutter pub cache repair && rm -f ios/Podfile ios/Podfile.lock pubspec.lock  &&  flutter pub get && flutter pub run build_runner clean

Comment: Hello @Hady, just got this error for the last command                                                                          

flutter pub run build_runner clean                                                


Could not find package "build_runner". Did you forget to add a dependency?
pub finished with exit code 65

Comment: Yes I’m sorry, you need to install this package https://pub.dev/packages/build_runner

Comment: unfortunately, did not work, i still get the same error as in the picture